# Guzzlehttp error when I use coinbase/coinbase php library in Codeigniter project

Tags: php, codeigniter, coinbase-api, guzzle, coinbase-php

Hello I am using coinbase/coinbase php library in Codeigniter project. I tried to get account using $client->getAccount($account_id);, But this gives error like following.

```
Message: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
Filename: /var/www/html/application/third_party/coinbase-php/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php

Line Number: 203
```

This code is normal and it was working earlier without any issue. Can anyone give me some ideas to try?

Comment: You need to set `false` to SSL in your Curl request. Because your localhost is not SSL.

Comment: still getting the same error. I have set verify to false but still getting the same error. The same code is working fine in localhost.